# Can't add a BOOLEAN column to a table in my Derby database

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, derby

I am using NetBeans and I am struggling with adding a BOOLEAN column to my table for my Derby database.

> Unable to execute command:
>   create table "APP".CLASS
>   (
>       TEST BOOLEAN
>   )
>   BOOLEAN cannot be used for the version 10.6 or any version before 10.6. You need to upgrade your database to 10.7 or any higher version.

But then when I checked my version, I found out that I have version 10.11.

What might be the reason for that?

Comment: If you are making modifications to an existing database then you should check the version of the *database format* with `IJ` using the instructions [here](http://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/VersionInfo#Derby_database_format_version). Even though you are running the latest and greatest version of the Derby *software* you may still be working with a *database* that was created with an older (pre-10.7) version.

Comment: If your database was created with an older version of derby,you can upgrade the database by following the derby docs

Comment: I couldn't solve the problem by that. Do you think that it could be the driver? Maybe the driver is old or something.

Comment: Nevermind, problem solved with your advices. Thanks!

Comment: @DennisvonEich: Would you mind adding the correct answer as an answer to this stack overflow question? Future visitors will be thankful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this problem was that I **upgraded** the database.